# Cannot log into Ubuntu while Windows is hibernated

Tags: dual-boot, windows, windows-10, hibernate

I use dual booting system which has Ubuntu and Windows 10. Very often I use hibernate feature in Windows 10. After that I tried to log into ubuntu but it does not allow me to do so. It does not even show Ubuntu logo screen.

Comment: Does GRUB show up?

Comment: no. Only blank screen shown up on my screen